# Pass argument to void function

Tags: c++

How to pass argument line to void? it keep show error the data type should be

> line [100][260]

I try other ways like

> wchar_t * line[][]

still can't

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

  void test(DWORD a, wchar_t * line[])
    {

        unsigned int i;

        for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            wcout << line[i];
        }

    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE *pFile;
        wchar_t *file = L"d:\\a.txt";
        wchar_t line[100][MAX_PATH];
        unsigned int a = 0;
        if (_wfopen_s(&pFile, file, L"r, ccs = UNICODE") == 0)
        {
            while (fgetws(line[a], 100, pFile))
            {
                a++;
            }
        }

        test(a, line);

        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Replace `void test(DWORD a, wchar_t * line[])` with `void test(const std::wstring& line)`, and get a few good books on C++.

Comment: @Claudia: Your function wants a 1-dimensional array of pointers.  You are trying to pass it a 2-dimensional array of chars.  NOT the same thing!

Comment: @IInspectable is there no way to pass wchar_t? i want wchar_t.

Comment: @IInspectable: `const std::wstring&` and `wchar_t*[]` are very different things. One is a single string, the other is an array of strings

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah i know that. but i don't know how to pass that multi dimensional array to void. i try many thing but can't.

Comment: Of course there is a way. If you are writing C code it is the only way. In C++, take advantage of C++. And since this question happens to be tagged [tag:c++], why are you asking for a C solution?

Comment: @Claudia: you are going about this all wrong. You can't use a 2D array of chars where a 1D array of pointers is expected.  You need to re-write this code to at least create a second array that contains pointers to the first array's elements

Comment: @RemyLebeau: True. I got distracted by a formal parameter holding a set of lines being called `line`. Use a `std::vector<std::wstring>` then.

Answer (score 0):

Your function wants a 1-dimensional array of pointers to null-terminated strings. But you are trying to pass it a 2-dimensional array of chars instead.  They are NOT the same thing!

At the very least, you can create a second array that contains pointers to the elements of the first array, eg:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <windows.h>

void test(DWORD a, wchar_t * lines[])
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        std::wcout << lines[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *pFile;
    wchar_t *file = L"d:\\a.txt";
    wchar_t lineData[100][MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t* lines[100];
    wchar_t *line;

    unsigned int a = 0;
    if (_wfopen_s(&pFile, file, L"r, ccs = UNICODE") == 0)
    {
        do
        {
            line = lineData[a];

            if (!fgetws(line, MAX_PATH, pFile))
                break;

            size_t len = wcslen(line);
            if ((len > 0) && (line[len-1] == L'\n'))
                line[--len] = 0;

            lines[a] = line;
        }
        while (++a < 100);

        fclose(pFile);
    }

    test(a, lines);

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, since you are using C++ anyway, you should be using C++ functionality instead of C functionality to read the file, eg:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void test(const std::vector<std::wstring> &lines)
{
    for (std::wstring &line : lines) {
        std::wcout << line << std::endl;
    }

    /* or: prior to C++11:

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
        std::wcout << lines[i] << std::endl;
    }

    or:

    for (std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = lines.begin(); iter != lines.end(); ++iter) {
        std::wcout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
    */
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> lines;
    std::wstring line;

    std::wifstream file(L"d:\\a.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(file, line)) {
            lines.push_back(line);
        }
        file.close();
    }

    test(lines);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That, and range-based for loops. Saves a needless variable, and an opportunity for a bug.

Comment: can i ask u from your view. is there perfomance different with c and c++ ways? is fast noticeable?

Comment: @Claudia: it is not really about performance, it is about doing "the right thing", safely and accurately.  C is not C++.  If you are going to use C++, use it the way it is meant to be used.  But, if you are worried about performance, then profile your code to see what works best for your needs.

Comment: Not trying to nitpick, but that should really be `for (auto const& line : lines)`. There's no need to repeat types. That, too, removes an opportunity for a bug.